# How to let any server user modify files created by a samba guest on a public share (and the other way around)?

Tags: linux, samba, permissions

I have a linux server running samba with a public share accepting guest connections. Any window box on the network can edit/remove files on the share as long as the files are created by a guest (i.e. through samba).

Now, some users use ssh to access the server and add files. But they can't remove files by samba guests. Similarly, guests can't edit/remove the files made by ssh users.

How can I make a real free-for-all public share where anyone can do anything in a specific folder? The folder in question is a mount point of an ext4 filesystem, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

1) ssh users will be able to change/delete samba created files if the share is configured with the following options in smb.conf

```
   create mode = 0777
   directory mode = 0777
```

2) assuming the guest account is "nobody", samba access may change/delete ssh users files if :

- samba share mount-point is configured to propagate the group nobody to files created from ssh access setgid, for example with /home/share as share:

  chgrp nobody /home/share

  chmod g+s /home/share
- ssh users must have their umask set to 0002 ( => this is usually done by default for all in /etc/profile).